Problem when integrating django project with deep learning model using h5 file
after i make all things in django project and have the h5 file of deep learning model using CNN , and when running the development server , and uploading image ,
the view function code
import os
import numpy as np
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import ImageUploadForm
from .models import UploadedImage
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from PIL import Image

def upload_image(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            image_instance = form.save()
            image_path = os.path.join('media', str(image_instance.image))
            prediction = predict_disease(image_path)
            return render(request, 'prediction_result.html', {'prediction': prediction})
    else:
        form = ImageUploadForm()
    return render(request, 'upload_image.html', {'form': form})

def predict_disease(image_path):
    model = load_model(r'C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\testingModelH5\models\EfficientNetB1-Skin-disease-b1-87.h5')
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    image = image.resize((224, 224))
    image_array = np.array(image) / 255.0
    image_array = np.expand_dims(image_array, axis=0)
    prediction = model.predict(image_array)
    
    return prediction

the error occurs below
Error when deserializing class 'DepthwiseConv2D' using config={'name': 'block1a_dwconv', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32', 'kernel_size': [3, 3], 'strides': [1, 1], 'padding': 'same', 'data_format': 'channels_last', 'dilation_rate': [1, 1], 'groups': 1, 'activation': 'linear', 'use_bias': False, 'bias_initializer': {'module': 'keras.initializers', 'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}, 'registered_name': None}, 'bias_regularizer': None, 'activity_regularizer': None, 'bias_constraint': None, 'depth_multiplier': 1, 'depthwise_initializer': {'module': 'keras.initializers', 'class_name': 'VarianceScaling', 'config': {'scale': 2.0, 'mode': 'fan_out', 'distribution': 'truncated_normal', 'seed': None}, 'registered_name': None}, 'depthwise_regularizer': None, 'depthwise_constraint': None}.
Exception encountered: Unrecognized keyword arguments passed to DepthwiseConv2D: {'groups': 1}
i asked chatgpt and it showed me this
It seems like you're encountering an error related to loading a Keras/TensorFlow model in your Django project. The error message indicates that there's an issue with deserializing a layer in your model, specifically a DepthwiseConv2D layer, due to unrecognized keyword arguments.
The error message suggests that the DepthwiseConv2D layer in your model is encountering an issue due to the 'groups': 1 parameter. This parameter is not typically used in DepthwiseConv2D layers in Keras/TensorFlow, which is why it's causing an error during deserialization.
To resolve this issue, you'll need to check the model definition and ensure that it is compatible with the Keras/TensorFlow version you're using. Specifically, you may need to remove or modify any custom parameters that are causing conflicts during deserialization.
Here are a few steps you can take to troubleshoot and resolve the issue:
Check model architecture: Review the architecture of your deep learning model and ensure that all layers and parameters are compatible with the version of Keras/TensorFlow you're using.
Verify layer parameters: If you've defined custom parameters for any layers, ensure that they are correctly specified and compatible with the layer types you're using.
Update Keras/TensorFlow: Ensure that you're using the latest version of Keras/TensorFlow. Sometimes, compatibility issues can arise due to outdated versions.
Debugging: You can try printing out the model summary or inspecting the model configuration to identify any discrepancies or unexpected parameters.
Consult documentation: Refer to the official documentation for Keras/TensorFlow to understand the correct usage and parameters for the layers in your model.
By carefully reviewing your model architecture and parameters, you should be able to identify and resolve the issue causing the error during deserialization. If you need further assistance, feel free to provide more details about your model architecture and any custom parameters you've defined.
enter image description here
i want to know what is this error , and caused by what whether it by django or problem with the h5 itself? , and how to solve it ?
